# local variable 'allLibrary' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I can't seen to understand what the issue here is, I am getting an error that local variable 'allLibrary' referenced before assignment, Please help

```
@app.route('/', methods =['GET','POST'])
def add():
    if request.method =='POST':
        bookName=(request.form['bookName'])
        authorName =(request.form['author'])
        genre = request.form['type']
        library = library(bookName=bookName, authorName=authorName, genre = genre)
        db.session.add(library)
        db.session.commit()    
    allLibrary = library.query.all()
    
    return render_template('index.html', allLibrary=allLibrary)
```

Comment: Is this the only instance where you are using/updating the value of `allLibrary` and `library`?

Comment: yes, this is the only instance in which I used allLibrary and library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment error is raised when you try to assign a value to a local variable before it has been declared. You can solve this error by ensuring that a local variable is declared before you assign it a value.

So to fix this make sure that the `allLibrary` variable is declared before you're accessing it. It could also be a [Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp) problem.

However it would seem that `library` is not assigned a value if the `if` statement fails, so you should probably ensure that that is within scope as well.